# Heroku can not find groovy dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, groovy

I have error when deploy my spring-boot microservices in Heroku for missing public library

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project config: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.test.config:config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact **org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.5.8**
>   in spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone) -> [Help 1]

It is similar to error described in [Failed to collect Maven dependencies in Java HelloWorld when deploying to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587073/failed-to-collect-maven-dependencies-in-java-helloworld-when-deploying-to-heroku), but not impact local repositories.

Do you have any idea why he looking only in spring repo and not into central maven?

Comment: Do you have a custom settings.xml? If not you can try to provide a settings.xml which tells to use the central maven repo. But without a custom settings.xml it should request the maven central..  [check this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml)

Comment: No, this is not helped me. There are and others dependencies which is propper downloaded from maven central. The problem is just with groovy-all pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found where is the problem.

must be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

My pom missed this

```
<type>pom</type>
```